# AWS waf and cloudfront association doesn't show request data in the web ACL dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-waf

I have previously configured the AWS waf and its corresponding web ACL manually in the AWS dashboard and then associated it with a Cloudfront distribution and it worked perfectly. Now that I have created the process in Terraform and associated it with the same distribution (manually associated it), I get no data of the sampled requests in the web ACL dashboard. I have waited for over 48 hours from when I associated the web ACL with the Cloudfront distribution.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your Terraform code, you have to enable the `sampled_requests_enabled` attribute to have the sample data.

```
  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "friendly-metric-name"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }
```

References:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!
I added visibility_config for the web ACL as well as each rule.